# MYSQL getting a user with latest purchase

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database query question.

My USER table set up is like this..

```
Id  |  PIN | biz_id | active_ind
--- | ---------------------------
 1  |  123 |  NULL  |     Y
 2  |  456 |   1    |     Y
 3  |  789 |  NULL  |     N
 4  |  012 |   2    |     Y
```

and my USER_PURCHASE table is like this

```
id    user_id     date       amount   
---|----------|------------|--------|
1  |     1    | 2014-04-03 |    5   |
2  |     2    | 2015-03-04 |    5   | 
5  |     3    | 2014-04-03 |    6   | 
3  |     4    | 2015-03-03 |    6   | 
4  |     2    | 2015-03-04 |    7   | 
6  |     3    | 2013-03-03 |    7   | 
7  |     4    | 2013-12-24 |    8   | 
8  |     4    | 2013-01-01 |    8   |
```

I am trying to write a query that will return user.id, user.pin, user_purchase.date for ACTIVE users whom have NOT made a purchase within the past 13 months.

I have tried to write the query as follows:

```
SELECT max( date ) AS mdate, `user_id` , `users`.`pin`
FROM `users_purchases`
INNER JOIN `users` ON `users_purchases`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `users`.`active_ind` = 'Y'
AND `users`.`biz_id` = NULL
GROUP BY `users`.`pin`
HAVING mdate < DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 13
MONTH )
```

but I suspect that is not the correct way of doing it.

Can someone please help with this and MOST IMPORTANTLY explain why the correct way of doing it is in fact correct - I would really like to understand this.      THANKS!

Comment: is your date field a date or a string? because string should have ansi format  `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Yes the date is a proper timestamp..just wrote it hastily. Will make the change now.

Comment: why you have `users.biz_id = NULL ` ??

Comment: because some customers are attached to a business and others are not..

Comment: Can you include your expected result and what result are you having right now. Looks to me your query is ok.

Comment: Honestly the only problem I see with your query is that you're saying `AND users.biz_id = NULL` instead of `AND users.biz_id IS NULL` these are different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.pin,
    max(up.date) mdate
FROM
    User u
    LEFT JOIN User_Purchase up ON u.Id = up.user_id
WHERE
    u.active_ind = 'Y'
    and u.biz_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
    u.id,
    u.pin
HAVING 
    mdate IS NULL or
    mdate < DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 13 MONTH )
```

you can leave off the `mdate IS NULL or` if you only want users who have actually made a purchase +13 months ago

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ac4f8/3)

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct because inner join users_purchases will automatically filter out users who have never made any purchase.

```
select distinct a.id, a.pin
from users a
left join users_purchases b on a.id = b.user_id and b.mdate >= curdate() - interval 13 month
where a.active_ind = 'Y' and a.biz_id is null and b.id is not null;
```

Here we used a left join on any purchases within the past 13 months. There will be a row for every user due to the left join. For users who have made any purchase within 13 months, users_purchases.id will not be null, and we filter them out by `b.id is not null` in the where statement.

Comment: When I try to run that, i am getting the date field (which i wanted to select) coming back NULL. Why would that be?

Comment: @ackerchez, which date would you like to return? the most recent purchase date? do we show null for users who have never made purchase?

Answer (score 0):

I would first filter the users by the date, then by the other fields (which I imagine will be less likely to fail, I mean, most users will be active) and then get te fields you want to show. I usually separate things from one JOIN to the other because it is also clearer to read

```
SELECT user_last_purchase.mdate, u.pin, u.id
FROM
(

  SELECT max( date ) AS mdate, user_id

  FROM users_purchases

  GROUP BY user_id

) user_last_purchase

RIGHT JOIN users u
ON u.id = user_last_purchase.user_id

WHERE `users`.`active_ind` = 'Y'
AND `users`.`biz_id` = NULL
AND user_last_purchase.mdate < DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 13 MONTH )
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your query is `users.biz_id = NULL` should be `users.biz_id IS NULL`

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/633f3a/4)

```
SELECT max( p_date ) AS mdate, u.`id` , u.`pin`
FROM users  u
JOIN user_purchases up
  ON u.`id` = up.`user_id` 
WHERE u.`active_ind` = 'Y' 
  AND u.`biz_id` IS NULL 
GROUP  BY u.`pin` 
HAVING mdate < Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 13 month) ;
```

There is room for improvement.

Like use `left join` to return new users without purchases. But there is none on your data.

make `group by` for each field on the select list, but mySql allow your format even when isnt ANSI.

```
  GROUP BY u.`id` , u.`pin`
```